# Keep text after background image during zooming

Tags: html, css, css-position, jsfiddle, zooming

In this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bcc8jwmm/ I want to keep text bellow background image. Using `top-padding` or `position: relative` is possible to get it but after zooming in/out the text is not exactly bellow image. How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using viewport units `vmin` or `vmax`.

**[Updated Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bcc8jwmm/1/)**

```css
body {
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsSKLt4iKH3QPxeZFYmxwOVKZl84p0t1EQVvBMR5OlRbJioE_f)  no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
}
p {
    position: relative;
    top: 50vmax;
}
```

```html
<p>text</p>
```

Comment: This is better but not exactly what I want.